# TYPE_STEP_COUNTER cannot be resolved or is not a field Android KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to develop a Step Counter app using the KitKat SDK. But I keep getting this error and the Sensor class does not have TYPE_STEP_COUNTER in it.

Can someone please help me identify the issue?

**Update:** *Adding the code here:*

```
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mStepDetector = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    mUiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I've updated the post with the code.

Comment: is your api 19? see table 1 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html. Also Quoting docs "Step detector and counter sensors are available on Nexus 5, and we're working with our chipset partners to bring them to new devices as soon as possible."

Comment: post the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what @Dark has to say. This sensors are added in Android API Level 19 with KitKat OS Version.You need to change the Target SDK version in your Application Manifest file as below.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Please also do try to do the following if it is not set to API LEVEL 19.

1) Right click on your project in the package explorer.
2) Click on Properties(Second Last option).
3) Go to Android in the window that opens.
4) Change project Build Target values to  "Target : Android 4.4.2", "Platform : 4.4.2" and "API Level : 19"
5) Apply , OK and you should be set to use TYPE_STEP COUNTER and TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem using the int value of the Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR instead of the constant itself; the value is '18'.
All other attempts don't work, I have updated sdk and use the target 19.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

You should update your SDK and change the target SDK to 19 from the manifest

and change the project sdk at first create 
because this feature is added only in kitkat 19 API